# Parsing HTML in Python - Some pages work and some don't...?

Tags: python, parsing, xpath, python-requests, lxml

Using the following script:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

gameUrl = 'http://store.401games.ca/catalog/2415520/caylus'
page = requests.get(gameUrl)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

stock = tree.xpath('//*[@id="stock"]/span[1]/div/*/text()')[0]

print stock
```

It will correctly display the stock level listed on the page. (1 at this time)

```
gameUrl = 'http://store.401games.ca/catalog/2415324/ticket-to-ride'
```

It displays the stock as 68, which is incorrect. (I have no idea where 68 is even coming from).

I tried this with a LOT of pages from this site and 90% of them work correctly using this script. But the other 10% fail and give random numbers...some are quite different like 68 instead of 30. Or 1100 instead of 30. Some are closer, like 12 instead of 9. I have no idea what is happening.

Does anyone have an idea of what may be the problem?

Comment: It sounds like your xpath expression is simply wrong for  the failing pages.  The first thing to do is spend some time examining the content of those pages to see how it differs from the pages that work.

Comment: @larsks it's not that I suspect. If you would open the page, you can notice that `quantity: 68` "flashing" before the correct `quantity: 30` shows up. Interesting problem to solve, I'd say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would open the page in the browser, you would see the `Quantity: 68` flashing before it changes to `Quantity: 30`.

At first, I thought there is an XHR request that dynamically gets the product availability from a certain endpoint after the page is loaded and almost started to provide a usual answer about browser automation, but the problem here is different.

If you would open the Network tab in browser developer tools, you may see the `store.js` javascript file being loaded. At the beginning of the script, you can see:

```
if(stock>30) { $('div.availability span').text( "30" ); }
var instock = $('div.availability').text();
instock = instock.replace("In-Stock", "Quantity");
```

What it means is that, if the quantity is more than 30, it is "manually" set to 30.

Comment: Epic board game, by the way. Love it.

Comment: Oh wow...that's very interesting.

It just doesn't explain the one case where Qty 9 was displayed as 12. I'll try to look more closely...thanks.

edit: Although, now I can't remember which one had that problem and I'm wondering if I just looked at the wrong line or something and that one was human error...